# Add Views when scrolling android

Tags: java, android, scrollview, dynamic-values

I am looking for a way to add View when scrolling through the ScrollView in android.
I dont want to add all the Views when app starts, I want to add them when user scroll, thats for saving the memory. How can I do that, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use a list view. For a general overview and lots of great info, see the google I/O talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

And for a tutorial: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: No, I dont want to use it, I am using a HorizontalScrolView, ListView is verticle...

Comment: Then the only other built in choice is Gallery. Its not designed for quite the same efficiency/size lists as ListView, but it will work. Alternatively you need to roll your own (in which case your question is too general for anyone to help you much).

Comment: I will try the Gallery then, tx, btw How can I load the images dynamically to the gallery ?

Comment: Thats a much more complicated question. Essentially fire off an async task, or a runnable on a thread pool in getView() in your gallery adapter to load the image, and then set the imageDrawable to be the loaded image. You will need to make sure that the view hasn't been recycled though, so in getView() set the tag of the imageView to be whatever you're using to identify your images and then only set the image in your tasks if the tag on the view still matches the one for the image the task loaded.

Comment: I hv tried to do this for a ListView but some images are inserting in wrong views...

Comment: Its probably because of the tag issue I mentioned. Your tasks are completing after your views have been recycled and used for some other image (and another task has been started for the second image). Setting the tags on the views as I described should solve this. Another thing to look at is here: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/XmlAdapters/src/com/example/android/xmladapters/ImageDownloader.html